# Android studio not reflecting changes, new changes are not visible in the app that I made through java and xml code

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I have hedgehog version of android studio....I did programming of my project in giraffe version but I had to  update that version because that was not working also due to some errors i had to update it.....now whenever I am connecting my mobile with my laptop with USB and trying to run the project, the app is not displaying the new changes I made or I am making, it's still showing those old changes.

I tried "clean project, run, rerun, rebuild", I also tried this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsxGt.jpg),   And this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHhFa.jpg)

,And this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/owiyJ.jpg) and all of them...but nothing is working for me.....I want to see all those new changes to appear in my app that I recently made....cuz iam still working on my project ....

Comment: Computers and smartphones have built-in screen shot function. Please use them and don't make blurred low quality photos of the screen.